# <form:form action in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an spring application with this welcome page in the web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>/search/search.do</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and this controller

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/search.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private String initForm(@ModelAttribute("searchForm") final SearchForm SearchForm, 
                             BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale) {

        sessionHelper.checkSessionAttributes(request,  locale);
        return "searchView";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/performDevicesearch.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private String performDeviceSearch(@ModelAttribute("searchForm") final SearchForm SearchForm, 
                             BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale) {

        sessionHelper.checkSessionAttributes(request,  locale);
        return "searchView";
    }           
}
```

and this JSP

```
<form:form commandName="searchForm" name="simpleSearchForm" id="simpleSearchForm"  method="post" action="search/performproductsearch.do" class="TTWForm1"   >
```

so I put this in the URL

http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices

Then I submit and I see this in the URL

http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices/search/performproductsearch.do

Then I submit again but I see this in the URL (!?)

```
http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices/search/search/performproductsearch.do
```

Comment: of course as you entered a relative url for the action, that part will be appended to the URL.

Comment: yes, but I I put /search/performproductsearch.do I got a 404--Not Found ! http://127.0.0.1:7001/search/performproductsearch.do

Comment: Sure because you should include the context. Use the `url` tag to create a absolute url and use that value for the action.